# Call different (localized) view based on current culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internationalization

I'm using `LocalizationAttribute` which implements `ActionFilterAttribute` to localize views. I simply put `[Localize]` on controller. I was using LocalizeStrings.resx files to apply based on which language is on current thread. Everything works for this simple case (with localized strings). Now I want to localize complete pages (not just strings).

To acomplish this which approach do you use?

Do I need to identify which thread is current on controller and based on that value to call view:

```
public ActionResult AboutUs()
{
    switch (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name)
    {
        case "en-US":
            return View("EnglishUSView");               
        case "de-DE":
            return View("GermanView");              
        default:
            return View(); 
    }
    return View();
}
```

or do you recommend something else ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend to simply extended `RazorViewEngine` and override `FindPartialView` and `FindView` in order to inform ViewEngine to look is there view with current culture inside thread. If that page cannot be found than proceed as usuall.

1. Extend `RazorViewEngine`
2. Inside View folder there should be (assuming that english is default lang.) `Index.cshtml` and `Index.de-DE.cshtml`
3. Modify `Global.asax.cs` file, inside application start you should call localized view engine (the one which implements RazorViewEngine)

**Controller**

```
no further modification needed
```

**Views**

```
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
/Views/Home/Index.de.DE.cshtml
```

**Helper**

```
public class LocalizedRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
   public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView ...
   public override ViewEngineResult FindView...
}
```

**ApplicationStart**

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new LocalizedRazorViewEngine());
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are numerous ways to achieve this but you can follow this one below.

Firstly you can assume some naming convention for the views, by adding culture suffix to their names i.e. ViewName_**en-US**.cshtml, ViewName_**pl-PL**.cshtml, etc.

If so, don't construct these names in each action separately based on the current culture. Just write common logic which takes care of that - base controller with overriden `OnActionExecuted` method:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

        var view = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
        if(view != null)
        {
            var viewName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(view.ViewName) 
                               ? filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() 
                               : view.ViewName;  // retrieve the custom view name if provided or default action name otherwise
            var cultureName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
            var localizedViewName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", viewName, cultureName);  // construct composite, culture-aware name 
            if (ViewExists(localizedViewName))  // safety check in case not all your views are localized - if so, just return the default name
            {
                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = localizedViewName };
            }                        
        }            
    }

    private bool ViewExists(string name)
    {
        var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, name, null);
        return result.View != null;
    }
}
```

Actions don't require any localization handling right now:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController 
{
    public ActionResult AboutUs()
    {            
        // (...) nothing special here
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would usually implement the rule in a Viewengine. Its easier than it sounds.

http://biasecurities.com/2010/01/localized-asp-net-mvc-views-using-a-localizedviewengine/

Comment: The implementation described in the article is buggy and won't work, at least for MVC 5.2.6
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ViewEngineCollection.cs#L154-L155
As you can see, the framework tries to locate view in the cache, then search them on the file system. The approach described in the article tries to find localized view first, and if it's not found, then return non-localized. The framework will cache non-localized view in the case and will return it for other localization, even if you have the localizations.